most efficient way to draw a gradient Objective-C (currently NSColorWell is lagging when moving color sliders)
Hello I have an NSGradient which I had hoped to drawin to the rect using the following code:
 [g drawInRect:[self bounds] angle:90];

However the issue is to get the PDF data using the below produces a black color rather than the gradient.
[myView dataWithPDFInsideRect:myView.bounds];

My solution currently is to create an NSImage from the gradient drawn on a rect - and draw the image - but obviously the performance of drawing this is bad - especially when changing colours.
I am trying to use the gradient as a background which you can change the colors with objects drawn on top.
Is there a better way to draw a gradient which works with dataWithPDFInsideRect, that's efficient so the NSColorWell sliders don't lag?
I'm sure there musy be an efficient way but i'm obviously looking in the wrong direction!

Best way to draw a gradient is to attach image with gradient. If gradient linear you can use resizable image with 1 pixel width.

That is what I am doing - I am using a linear gradient I have tried reducing the size of the image to 1 pixel and even 20 or 30px previously however I notice a stepping on the gradient - so it's not a smooth gradient. So right no i'm using 850px which probably isn't helping with performance.
I also wonder if drawinrect is the most efficient way as when I move the sliders in the color panel from my nscolorwell it's really lagging.

Tough to say, without seeing more of your code, but, here is a quick example...
Start a new MacOS app project
Add a new NSView class named "SimpleGradientView`:
SimpleGradientView.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface SimpleGradientView : NSView
@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END


SimpleGradientView.m
#import "SimpleGradientView.h"

@implementation SimpleGradientView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    NSGradient *bg = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithColors:@[NSColor.redColor, NSColor.yellowColor]];
    [bg drawInRect:self.bounds angle:90.0];
}

@end


ViewController.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ViewController : NSViewController
@end


ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SimpleGradientView.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    SimpleGradientView *gradView;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.preferredContentSize = NSMakeSize(600.0, 480.0);
    
    gradView = [SimpleGradientView new];
    
    // Create a button
    NSButton *button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(150, 125, 100, 50)];
    [button setTitle:@"Save as PDF"];
    [button setButtonType:NSButtonTypeMomentaryPushIn];
    [button setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleRounded];
    [button setTarget:self];
    [button setAction:@selector(saveAsPDF:)];
    
    // Create a label
    NSTextField *label = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(40, 20, 200, 45)];
    [label setStringValue:@"Hello, PDF!"];
    [label setBezeled:NO];
    [label setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [label setEditable:NO];
    [label setSelectable:NO];
    
    NSFontManager *fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
    NSFont *boldItalic = [fontManager fontWithFamily:@"Verdana"
                                              traits:NSBoldFontMask|NSItalicFontMask
                                              weight:0 size:48];
    
    // create an image view with image
    NSImage *img = [NSImage imageWithSystemSymbolName:@"apple.logo" accessibilityDescription:@""];
    NSImageView *iv = [NSImageView new];
    iv.image = img;
    iv.imageScaling = NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown;
    iv.contentTintColor = NSColor.cyanColor;
    
    [label setFont:boldItalic];
    [label setTextColor:NSColor.blueColor];
    
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    
    gradView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:gradView];
    
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [gradView addSubview:label];
    
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [gradView addSubview:iv];
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        
        [button.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor constant:20.0],
        [button.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor],
        
        [gradView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:button.bottomAnchor constant:20.0],
        [gradView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor constant:40.0],
        [gradView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor constant:-40.0],
        [gradView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor constant:-40.0],
        
        [label.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:gradView.topAnchor constant:20.0],
        [label.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:gradView.centerXAnchor],
        
        [iv.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:label.bottomAnchor constant:20.0],
        [iv.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:gradView.centerXAnchor],
        [iv.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:gradView.bottomAnchor constant:-20.0],
        [iv.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:iv.heightAnchor],
        
    ]];
    
}

- (void)saveAsPDF:(id)sender {
    NSData *pdfData = [gradView dataWithPDFInsideRect:[gradView bounds]];
    NSSavePanel *savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    [savePanel setAllowedFileTypes:@[@"pdf"]];
    [savePanel setNameFieldStringValue:@"MyView.pdf"];
    
    [savePanel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSModalResponse result) {
        if (result == NSModalResponseOK) {
            NSURL *fileURL = [savePanel URL];
            [pdfData writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];
            NSLog(@"PDF saved to %@", fileURL);
        }
    }];
}

- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];
}

@end

When run, it should look like this:

Clicking the button will save the gradient view - along with its subviews - as a PDF file. Example: https://github.com/DonMag/SavePDFMacApp/blob/main/MyView.pdf
I posted the complete project here: https://github.com/DonMag/SavePDFMacApp

Edit
Curious... this is either a Bug, or there was a change that I can't find between Ventura and Sonoma
Using dataWithPDFInsideRect does not appear to render the gradient -- either using drawRect or using a CAGradientLayer.
Generating a gradient image looks to be a reliable approach.
I updated my GitHub repo with an example.

I have downloaded your example project and run it and the exported PDF has a black background too - at least in Sonomo 14.3.1 is it exporting with the gradient for you?

That is how it exports for me: https://imgur.com/a/SAF6oQU

@GeraldTheGerm - curious... I ran it first on Ventura, but I now see the problem when running on Sonoma. See the Edit to my answer.
